# How to change color of access modifiers in editor?

Tags: phpstorm

In order to improve readability of the code I want to try to assign different colors to `public`, `protected` and `private` keywords (green, orange and red respectively). How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible.

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33349
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22194
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80384

Right now none of them is not on the "to be implemented soon" list (based on "Fix versions" field).

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, it seems, that PHPstorm team could not care less about implementing that feature..

Comment: Well -- it all depends on votes. All those tickets have very little demand from users. Including me -- right now I do not see any real benefit of having such functionality. Surely -- I may change my opinion when I see it in action ... but right now I personally agree with JetBrains' devs -- why rush with implementing something that has very little to no demand. I'm not against it .. just do not see much profit for me in having it right now. But different people will have different opinions/priorities.