# PhpStorm 10.0: Change colors of top notification bar while editing remote host file?

Tags: phpstorm

[image: This is what I'm talking about]

I tried many different themes, and finally found one that I like the most editor-style-wise, but this bright bar in a dark theme ruins it for me. Couldn't really find anything about it in myTheme.icls file

Comment: I guess this comes as part of GUI Theme and not Editor Color Schema (your `.icls` file). Those are 2 separate things: first one has no configuration options (not editable) while and can be (`Colors & Fonts`). If I'm right -- you cannot do anything about it (unless you hack GUI Theme, which is part of IDE distribution so needs to be updated together with IDE). if I'm wrong -- then try going trough all available styles one by one looking for similar colors -- no other ideas right now.

Comment: One thing i've noticed is different themes have this bar in a color from different GUI Themes. And if i set my editor theme to use the Darcula GUI, it would be more than enough, but this setting is not in the .icls file, or is obfuscated somehow...

Comment: Try this one -- this is the best matching style I could find: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General --> Editor | Notification Background`. Thing is -- this kind of bar can have different colors: "general" yellow-ish, "successful" green and "problematic" red. That style (if it can affect this bar) should only control first one -- where the rest 2 are coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -- this is the best matching style I could find:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`
3. `Editor | Notification Background` styling element.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The error state of this bar is also of interest, but not that important, since most of the time i won't see it :)

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to give separate colors to keywords like "private function null new" and standard language constructs like "foreach if include break" ? In Colors & Fonts both of those are controlled by "Keywords"

Comment: That is not possible -- see this Answer for details/tickets to watch after: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40428285/783119